# How to realize slider widget , matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Here is my code. Please, I can't realize slider. When I change 'y' the columns in bar chart should change their colors and the horizontal line also should change its position. I've tried using a function but nothing happened. Help, please

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
%matplotlib notebook

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
               np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
               np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
               np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
              index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])


y = 40000

mean = list(df.mean(axis=1))
std = list(df.std(axis=1))
variance = [1.96*(std[i]/len(df.T)**0.5) for i in range(len(df))]

#figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.2)
barplot = plt.bar(list(df.index), mean, yerr=variance)
plt.xticks(list(df.index))

#adding hline
ax.axhline(y=y, color = 'black')
ax.text(1995.68, y, '{}'.format(y), va='center', ha="left", bbox=dict(facecolor="w",alpha=0.5))

#changing colors
bars = barplot.get_children()
for bar, mean, var in zip(bars, mean, variance):
    bar.set_color(((y<mean), 0, (y>mean), min(1, abs(y-mean)/var)))
    bar.set_edgecolor('black')

#slider
slider = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow')
slider_y = Slider(slider,
                label='y',
                valmin=0.0,
                valmax=50000,
                valinit=40000,
                valfmt='%1.0f')
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The [Slider Demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html) shows how to implement a slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Since you're editing in a notebook, I would suggest implementing [`ipywidgets`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html):**

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

y_slider = widgets.IntSlider(
    value= 40000,
    min=0,
    max= 50000,
    step=1000,
    description='Y',
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
)

# You can add this to your plot by using the following code:

# first, create a function for your plot
def plot_my_plot(df, y):
   mean = list(df.mean(axis=1))
   std = list(df.std(axis=1))
   variance = [1.96*(std[i]/len(df.T)**0.5) for i in range(len(df))]
   #figure
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.2)
   barplot = plt.bar(list(df.index), mean, yerr=variance)
   plt.xticks(list(df.index))

   #adding hline
   ax.axhline(y=y, color = 'black')
   ax.text(1995.68, y, '{}'.format(y), va='center', ha="left", bbox=dict(facecolor="w",alpha=0.5))

    #changing colors
   bars = barplot.get_children()
      for bar, mean, var in zip(bars, mean, variance):
          bar.set_color(((y<mean), 0, (y>mean), min(1, abs(y-mean)/var)))
          bar.set_edgecolor('black')


# Next, add values to your interactive plot
widgets.interact(plot_my_plot, y=y_slider, df=fixed(df))
```

*This should work!*